# when downloading a dependency jar, how to make its dependencies get downloaded

Tags: gradle, jar, compilation, dependencies, artifactory

I have built two jars and put them in Artifactory. One of the jars depends on the other (the dependency is in its build.gradle file). When I download the main jar as a dependency of my main app, the dependent jar is not downloaded. The only way I can get both is to put two compile statements in the build.gradle. How do I cause the dependent jar to also get downloaded?

The main jar file is user-cache.jar and it depends on blue-redis.jar. The build.gradle in the app that uses my main jar uses this compile statement:

```
compile(group: 'etd.user-cache', name: 'user-cache', version: '1.0.2', ext: '12.SNAPSHOT.jar')
```

The build.gradle for user-cache has this in it:

```
    compile(group: 'etd.blue-redis', name: 'blue-redis', version: '1.0.1', ext: '4.SNAPSHOT.jar')
```

When I build my app, it only gets user-cache.jar. That makes it necessary to put both compile statements in my app's build.jar

What should I do to cause the blue-redis.jar to also be downloaded without needing its compile statement?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using a maven repository in Artifactory.  When gradle is doing [dependency resolution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_resolution) it will attempt to download a POM file and check for transitive dependencies as well as parent poms which may list additional dependencies.

To get the desired behavior, when you publish the main jar to Artifactory you need to include in its POM file a dependency on the other JAR.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have been looking for a good example of a POM file and most are pretty confusing if I want to just have one jar with a dependency on one other jar. Could you recommend a link that shows a simple example of this. I am new to POM files, sorry...